# Test if template files (.tpl.php) are used by theme

Tags: theming

I've inherited a custom Drupal 7 theme with many template files. I'm sure lots of them aren't actually used by the website, and were part of the testing process.

Is there a method to list which .tpl.php files are being used in the website, or for a particular page?

Comment: Take a look at [Theme Developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer). Don't know how much a help it'll be, but possibly at least a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Just print the theme hook suggestion variable in any preprocess function in template.php

```
print_r($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']);
```

If you use the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) then

```
dpm($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']);
```

Comment: That doesn't list theme files in use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its 'right' because I'm new to Drupal, but I also inherited a Drupal site and I had the same problem.  I'm using custom Google Analytics events to track what URLs load certain things.  For example, every time a view is loaded it fires a custom GA event with the view's machine name and URL.  A few weeks later I can see exactly what views are used and where.